# What happens to run webapp when use radsplitter in masterpage?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I used `RadSplitter` in my `masterpage` and created my `webform` using `masterpage`.

But i have a problem with this component
I can use this but at run time `contentplaceholder` in my `webform`  has merged with the footer of page and I cant use it in seperate window.
Please help.

**masterpage**:

```
     <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Automation.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div style="border:5px solid black">
            <h3>Request an Account</h3>
            <p>Accounts will be activated pending the approval of the Administrator.</p>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your point being? Just place the ContentPlaceHolder in the master page inside the desired RadPane and the content will appear in there. The RadSplitter allows for inline content as well, see both [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/externalcontentloading/defaultcs.aspx) in action.